# Gradient descent for linear regression using numpy/pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, data-mining

I currently follow along *Andrew Ng's* [Machine Learning Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) on Coursera and wanted to implement the [gradient descent algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) in `python3` using `numpy` and `pandas`.

This is what I came up with:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_training_data(path):    # path to read data from
    raw_panda_data = pd.read_csv(path)

    # append a column of ones to the front of the data set
    raw_panda_data.insert(0, 'Ones', 1)

    num_columns = raw_panda_data.shape[1]                       # (num_rows, num_columns)
    panda_X = raw_panda_data.iloc[:,0:num_columns-1]            # [ slice_of_rows, slice_of_columns ]
    panda_y = raw_panda_data.iloc[:,num_columns-1:num_columns]  # [ slice_of_rows, slice_of_columns ]

    X = np.matrix(panda_X.values)   # pandas.DataFrame -> numpy.ndarray -> numpy.matrix
    y = np.matrix(panda_y.values)   # pandas.DataFrame -> numpy.ndarray -> numpy.matrix

    return X, y

def compute_mean_square_error(X, y, theta):
    summands = np.power(X * theta.T - y, 2)
    return np.sum(summands) / (2 * len(X))

def gradient_descent(X, y, learning_rate, num_iterations):
    num_parameters = X.shape[1]                                 # dim theta
    theta = np.matrix([0.0 for i in range(num_parameters)])     # init theta
    cost = [0.0 for i in range(num_iterations)]

    for it in range(num_iterations):
        error = np.repeat((X * theta.T) - y, num_parameters, axis=1)
        error_derivative = np.sum(np.multiply(error, X), axis=0)
        theta = theta - (learning_rate / len(y)) * error_derivative
        cost[it] = compute_mean_square_error(X, y, theta)

    return theta, cost
```

This is how one could use the code:

```
X, y = get_training_data(os.getcwd() + '/data/data_set.csv')
theta, cost = gradient_descent(X, y, 0.008, 10000)

print('Theta: ', theta)
print('Cost: ', cost[-1])
```

Where `data/data_set.csv` could contain data (model used: `2 + x1 - x2 = y`) looking like this:

```
x1, x2, y
0, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
1, 0, 3
0, 0, 2
2, 4, 0
4, 2, 4
6, 0, 8
```

**Output:**

```
Theta:  [[ 2.  1. -1.]]
Cost:  9.13586056551e-26
```

I'd especially like to get the following aspects of my code reviewed:

- Overall `python` style. I'm relatively new to `python` coming from a `C` background and not sure if I'm misunderstanding some concepts here.
- `numpy`/`pandas` integration. Do I use these packages correctly?
- Correctness of the gradient descent algorithm.
- Efficiency. How can I further improve my code?

Comment: You could use `np.zeros` to initialize `theta` and `cost` in your gradient descent function, in my opinion it is clearer. Also why uppercase X and lowercase y? I would make them consistent and perhaps even give them descriptive names, e.g. `input` and `output`. Finally, you could look into exceptions handling  e.g. for bad input data from pandas or invalid values for `learning_rate` or `num_iterations`.

Comment: @nluigi The notation comes from the machine learning course. X is a matrix and y is a vector, but you are probably right that I should rename the parameters or add an explaining comment.

Comment: Note you can also use `theta = np.zeros_like(X)` if you would like to initialize `theta` with an array of zeros with dimensions of `X`.

Comment: @nluigi Thank you for the tipp. Sadly `theta` doesn't have the same dimensions as `X`. Regardless I'll keep the `np.zeros_like(...)` function in the back of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Without having the insight (or, honestly, time) to verify your actual algorithm, I can say that your Python is pretty good.

Only minor stuff - this kind of comment - `# path to read data from` - should be turned into a PEP257-style docstring.

You should add a shebang at the top of your file, probably `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Otherwise, you're off to a good start.

Comment: I just added the shebang and made the script executable. It's honestly so much more comfortable than typing `python3 gradient_descent.py` all the time. Thank you for the tipps!

Answer (score 0):

I like your Python style. There is an issue with your algorithm though. numpy.repeat does not work the way you expect it to. Try this code:

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.matrix([1,2,3])    
y = 2
X = np.matrix(np.array(range(9)).reshape(3,3))
error = np.repeat((X * theta.T) - y, 3, axis=1)

print(error)

>>>[[ 6  6  6]
 [24 24 24]
 [42 42 42]]

print(np.dot(X, theta.T)-y)

>>>[[ 6]
 [24]
 [42]
```

Do you see how numpy.repeat returns a matrix although you want to return a vector?

Comment: Do you refer to my line `error = np.repeat((X * theta.T) - y, num_parameters, axis=1)`?. I thought about it and still think, that my calculation is correct. I calculate the heuristic function for the x-values via `X * theta.T`. The result is a matrix with a single column, where the i-th row contains the difference of the heuristic function for the x-values of the i-th training example and output value in the i-th training example. What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: Sry, my previous answer was wrong. I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`numpy.zeros(shape)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) to initialize the tetha and cost vectors with zeros.